# Which Azure Data center in US has the best performance for the other data centers in terms of network latency

Tags: performance, azure

I have a need that, I need to install a sql azure database in one US data center, then this database will be accessed/connected by an application that is running on multiple azure data centers in US (east, north, central, west, etc).

My question is:  which data center should i install the sql azure database, so that, my application on all other azure data center can achieve better performance in terms of network latency?

Right now i have no plan to replica the database or use any other options.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're going to be paying bandwidth charges for the datacenters that are querying the Azure SQL Database in your "main" datacenter.  Does the compute in the other regions have a need to read & write, or just read? Is the idea here to have multiple compute instances for geographic reasons, and a single "master" database?

Comment: @mcollier i am trying to migrate an application to azure, it is for enterprises, try to distribute it to different data centers so enterprise can pick up one that is close to them for performance reason. However, there is a master database for all account,  it needs read and write, but very minimum amout of data.

Comment: Makes sense. I think you'll have to do your own validation.  There isn't anything that indicates one region has bigger/faster connection than the others. A lot will depend on your connection to the internet.  I wouldn't worry about the Azure datacenter's connection - it's beefy.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any public, reliable numbers re: this question. Geographically speaking, I'd expect marginally lower latency if you put your database in a central datacenter, so US North or US South.

I feel obliged to note that I expect other concerns to be far more relevant to your performance concerns. Database design and indices make a huge difference, and all datacenters have fat pipes to the rest of the world. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check Azure Speed Test and chose the one with low latency:

http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/

PS: you can also enable Azure Traffic Manager to deal with that.

http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/services/traffic-manager/